# Prevent HTML5 standard video controls from fading out?

Tags: html, video, controls

Is it possible to prevent the HTML5 standard video controls from fading out? And to keep them visible at all times?

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to prevent video controls from fading.  Although it works, there must be a better way.  I hope someone with more Javascript/CSS knowledge will give a better solution (one that doesn't require constantly re-adding the "controls" attribute).

```
<video id="myvideo" controls="controls">
    <source src="myvideo.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8.0, vorbis"'></source>
</video>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var vidElem = document.getElementById("myvideo");

    vidElem.addEventListener('timeupdate', videoTimeUpdateHandler, false);

    function videoTimeUpdateHandler(e)
    {
        vidElem.setAttribute("controls","controls");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: There are WebKit test files that show ways to access the "MediaControlsElement".  I'm not enough of a Javascript programmer to understand them.  Maybe someone else can help:  https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/WebKit_LayoutTests/+/master/fullscreen/video-controls-override.html

Comment: The file above includes a "media-controls.js" file.   http://code.ohloh.net/file?fid=b980SJQzFzh5tgitVoTy1aYJjPM&cid=k9zDftQ-Nwk&s=&fp=529227&mp&projSelected=true#L0